# Cloud Foundry Java Applications on Windows Stack using Diego

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a windows 2012 server stack on cloud foundry.
I am trying to push a Java application(.war package) to this stack using Diego plugin.

The logs says that server started properly , but when i hit the application URL, I get a 404 error.

The same package  works perfectly fine on linux stack.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At the present time, Windows support is for running Windows apps.

> 1.) ASP .NET MVC (12-factor ASP.NET MVC apps compiled against .NET 3.5+ were tested most extensively) 
>   2.) Windows-compiled executables 
>   3.) Batch scripts (with a manually specified start command)

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-windows-msi/blob/master/docs/RELEASE-NOTES.md#supported-applications---known-to-work

Build packs will continue to run apps on Linux.